# Ruby Logging Issue

Tags: ruby, logging

Hello I am using Logger in Ruby in a project.

I have created explicitly a log file on debian linux under the root user. The `logLevel= INFO` and `OUTPUT=BOTH`.

When my controller runs it does write e.g. service is starting and the message that I am parsing but afterwards It doesn't write to log file anymore. I thought It could be a permission issue. I checked the permissions with the following command

```
 ls -l sa.gw.c.gpsglobal.log
 > -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 635K May 28 08:24 sa.gw.c.gpsglobal.log
```

was returned.
on Windows box When the controller tries to write to the fresh log file it says Log shifting failed, stream is closed.

Comment: It might be the permissions on the directory.  Also, check your disk isn't full.

Comment: Jhoc C. I have pasted above the permission list. does it show that it requires further permissions. because it were a permission problem. it wouldn't write two lines each time i run the controller

Comment: I think you are hitting the problem when it tries to rotate the log.  It might not be able to rename the log to a new file.  Directory permissions could prevent that.

Comment: John C.
I, [2014-05-28T11:37:23.030772 #1484]  INFO -- : Starting agent: Log Level=INFO
I, [2014-05-28T11:38:23.683922 #1484]  INFO -- : [0;33;49mPublisher: 05/28/2014 11:38 AM - 0 msgs/m[0m
I, [2014-05-28T11:39:00.061440 #1484]  INFO -- : Message: :M45405641-default-0/91;<S-1=8,2=6,3=42,4=392318><E-1,392273,4034.38044,N,11153.70579,W,0,0,0.9>!34668
This is what it writes in the log file. Next time it should log too but doesn't

Comment: My Logger Object
#<Log:0x00000001372e58 @logger=#<Logger:0x00000001372d40 @progname=nil, @level=1, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00000001372cf0 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00000001372c00 @shift_size=1048576, @shift_age="daily", @filename="/var/log/sa/sa.gw.p.gpsglobal.log", @dev=#<File:/var/log/sa/sa.gw.p.gpsglobal.log>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x00000001372bd8 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000001372ae8>>>>, @output="both">

Comment: Please post ls -al /var/log/sa
Also I think these diagnostics should go in your question.

Comment: John C.
Applied the command on file sa directory and It listed the permissions for all the files underneath.
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 109K May 28 13:01 sa.gw.c.gpsglobal.log
Is this possible that logger object disposes off itself?